# woocommerce hook when order is placed through REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to run some custom PHP code when an order is placed on a WooCommerce store. Currently, I am using `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook which is working perfectly for web front.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'order_confirmation',10, 3);
function order_confirmation($order_id,$oldstatus,$newstatus){  
    //my custom code...
}
```

But when an order is placed through API, this hook is not called.

Is there any hook that we can use to execute some php code when an order is placed through WooCommerce's Rest Api V2?

Comment: you can use the `woocommerce_new_order` action for that. 
`function on_new_order_created($order_id){ }
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'on_new_order_created' );`

Comment: @SumitParkash Thank you for your response. the woocommerce_new_order action works perfectly. Is there any action that is called when order status is changed? Basically, I need to execute some php code after payment is done for an order, means when order status is changed to processing.

Comment: you guys are great.. it worked..

Comment: Hello @AmitMittal action hook for order status change: `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed',...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are sending the **set_paid** property to `true`. It sets the status to processing and reduce stock items. if you need to to perform action when order payment is completed, you can use the **woocommerce_payment_complete** action hook.

```
function on_woocommerce_payment_complete($order_id){
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'on_woocommerce_payment_complete' 
);`
```

However the above hook only fire when order status was from the following array

`on-hold', 'pending', 'failed', 'cancelled`

before marking the payment completed.

For other order statues the following hook is fired.

`do_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status_' . $this->get_status(), $this->get_id() );`

For more detail you can check the

`public function payment_complete( $transaction_id = '' ) {`

define in
`woocommerce\includes\class-wc-order.php`